# jQuery - how to make a splitter to be at a middle when the screen been re-sized

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to use the next plugin - [LINK](http://methvin.com/splitter/)

As you can see it is well explained.

What I'm trying to do is very simple - when the code loads in the first time the splitter will be in the middle, and also if the screen size has been changed then also splitter will be at the middle (even if the splitter had been moved by the user before changing the windows size).

In order to do so I've tried the next simple code -

```
    <html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>jQuery Horizontal Splitter</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="plug/jquery-2.0.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="plug/jquery-splitter.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="plug/jquery-splitter.min.js"></script>


    <style>

        #MySplitter {
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 5px solid #aaa;
}
#MySplitter div {
    overflow: auto;
}
.splitter-bar-vertical {
    width: 5px;
    background: #aaa;
}

    </style>
    <script>


        $().ready(function () {
            $("#MySplitter").splitter();
        });


        $(window).resize(function () {
            var width = $(window).width();
            $("#MySplitter").css("width", width).trigger("resize");

});


    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="MySplitter">
        <div> Left content goes here </div>
        <div> Right content goes here </div>
    </div> 

</body>
</html>
```

So what am i doing wrong here?
Thanks for any kind of help

Comment: Did you try to use the following as described in the link you provided: resizeToWidth When you specify resizeToWidth: true, the splitter will automatically resize itself whenever the window.resize event fires. This is handy for the common situation where the splitter's size is proportional to the browser window width--for example, it has a fluid 100% width. By default, the splitter will only resize when it is sent a resize event.

Comment: @Xavjer - tried that as follows - '        $("#MySplitter").splitter({resizeToWidth: true});' - but it sure not working - the spiltter stays at the place I moved it to before changing the windows size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only need to include one `splitter.js` file - the `splitter.min.js` is just a minimised version of the same file.

Also the demos on that site use a very early version of jQuery (1.3) - this seems to have an impact on the plugin

[See this example](http://jsfiddle.net/e46heasp/)

It uses the earliest version of jQuery allowed on jsFiddle and seems to work, however if you change the jQuery library to v2.2 (or even v11) it will stop working

Updated code as per your comments:

```
var splitterDiv = $("#MySplitter"); 
splitterDiv.splitter();

 $(window).resize(function () {
     var width = splitterDiv.width() / 2;
     splitterDiv.trigger("resize", [width]);
 });
```

[Fully working example - needs to use jQuery 1.3](http://jsfiddle.net/e46heasp/4/)

Comment: Ok - but the thing is that when i move the splitter at your example link, and then re-size the preview section the splitter stays at his position and not moving back to the middle point - if I'm vhanging it to - ' $("#MySplitter").css("width", width/2).trigger("resize");' - any idea why?

Comment: Ah okay, you need to put the width into the resize function, not the css: http://jsfiddle.net/e46heasp/1/

Comment: ok, but now the spiltter can't be moved at all - so how can I make it movable  but back at the middle when the window size is changed

Comment: Ok the problem seems to be with the version of jQuery.  If you use jQuery 1.3 as in their demos, then the plugin will work as it is intended, if you usse newer versions then there are a lot of js errors being thrown.  [Check this link for a fully working version](http://jsfiddle.net/e46heasp/4/)